# Fuelphp: convert standard ORM model to model_temporal

Tags: fuelphp, fuelphp-orm

Using fuelphp, is there a way to modify an existing `\ORM\Model` to convert it to `\ORM\Model_Temporal`? I started looking into creating a migration, which needs to 1) add the necessary columns to my table (not difficult); 2) update the primary key to include the new columns as part of a compound primary key (difficult). The problem I am having is that I don't see a method in the [DBUtil](http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/database/dbutil.html) that performs this operation.

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `DBUtil` does not include a way to alter primary keys because the method of doing so differs between DB systems and `DBUtil` is not actually that aware what DBMS you are using.

To do this you will have to construct the query manually in your migration and use `DB::query()` to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is faced with the same task, here is what I ended up doing. My database is MySQL, the syntax may have to be changed if you're using a different DBMS. My original primary key was an auto-incrementing column named `id`.

```
class Modify_TableName_To_Temporal
{
    public function up()
    {
        \DBUtil::add_fields('tablename',array(
            'temporal_start'=>array('constraint'=>11, 'type'=>'int','default'=>0),
            'temporal_end'=>array('constraint'=>11, 'type'=>'int','default'=>2147483647),
        ));
        \DB::query('ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY id int, DROP PRIMARY KEY')->execute();
        \DB::query('ALTER TABLE tablename ADD PRIMARY KEY (id, temporal_start, temporal_end), MODIFY id int auto_increment')->execute();
    }

    public function down()
    {
        \DB::query('ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY id int, DROP CONSTRAINT primary')->execute();
        \DB::query('ALTER TABLE tablename ADD PRIMARY KEY (id), MODIFY id int auto_increment')->execute();
        \DBUtil::drop_fields('tablename',array('temporal_start','temporal_end'));
    }
}
```